# Multiple file upload duplating php and mysql

Tags: php

Please my multiple file upload is duplicating the file is on Github

https://github.com/komeee/Web.git

Comment: Please describe problem. What is duplicating? **WARMING: never use original name to store files on disk.** It can be prepared to attack you.

Comment: the pictures i am uploading...ok thanks..

Comment: in `for` you concat all filenames (L31) and inserts it on all iteration (L41). Change code to check and prepare data, and later to insert it

Comment: @bato3 am really not getting it clear go you  please help me edit it or explain it clearer ...thank you

Comment: You doing this: `for($i=0; $i<5; $i++) { concat_all_filenames; check_is_uploaded_file; INSERT concat_all_filenames} ` You should: `for($i=0; $i<5; $i++) { if(is_uploaded_file) add_file_name_to_filelist;}  INSERT only_valid_filelist; `

Comment: @bato3 Thanks i get now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need something like this:

```
<?php
 for($i =0 ; $i<count($_FILES['upload_images']['name']); $i++){  
        if($_FILES['upload_images']['error'][$i]) {
       //error - upload error
       $uploaded_images[]='default-image';
       continue;
        }
    if(!is_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload_images']['tmp_name'][$i])) {
        //error2 - no uploaded file
        $uploaded_images[]='default-image';
        continue;
    }
    if(!in_array($_FILES['upload_images']['type'][$i],['image/jpeg', 'image/png','...'])) {
        // error 3 - not a image
        $uploaded_images[]='default-image';
        continue;
    }
    $uploaded_images[]=your_function_to_save_file_and_generate_safe_filename($_FILES['upload_images']['tmp_name'][$i], 'pther params');
 }
$filename =  join('@@@', $uploaded_image);
$insert_sql = "INSERT INTO `blog_post` (`id`, `images`, `captions` , `title`  ) VALUES (? , ? , ? , ?)";
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt , $insert_sql)){
    echo "SQL error!! Contact Support";
}else{
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt , "ssss" , $null  ,$filename , $text , $title);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
}
```